# Where is RelayState parameter in OneLogin parameter?

Tags: java, saml, onelogin

My config is SP.
The "*onelogin.saml.properties*" file does not have the "*RelayState*" parameter !
Where is RelayState parameter ?
is it possible to disable it or change it ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not in the config file !
This is the parameter of the login method:

Auth auth = new Auth(request, response);
auth.login("https://host/rly.jsp");

Comment: not to post :  auth.login("");

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[OneLogin git repo-](https://github.com/SAML-Toolkits/java-saml#why-add-saml-support-to-my-software)
You will find **RelayState** Parameter in the configuration tab of OneLogin Administrator portal.

Once you initialise the Auth class, it will redirect it to mentioned jsp page.

```
Auth auth=new Auth(request,response);
auth.login("redirect_to_this_page.jsp");
```